# Detect HttpResponseRedirect and Get Header Data in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to capture an HttpResponseRedirect from a render within a function.

I have some success... but I want to be able to extract the Location.

For Example..

```
{'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'), 'location': ('Location', '/app/create/preview/')}
```

Is a response that I'm able to get using

```
xxx_response._headers
```

How do I decode this? Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I didn't try to just load the response into a dict.

This solved my problem.

```
>>> d = {'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'), 
'location': ('Location', '/job/create/preview/')}
>>> d['location'][0]
 'Location'
>>> d['location'][1]
'/job/create/preview/'
```